# how to handle nested fields generated by mongodb collection

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, csv, database-schema, database

I am new to mongodb. I exported my mongodb collection as csv file to import it in to my sql-server. The problem is that one of the field is nested. Can any one tell me how can I handle that field (address) so that it is inserted properly in sql server. So here is what I mean

The collection is 
Id | Name | Salary |               Address                            |
                                              | House No  | Street | City | Country|

Comment: Define "inserted properly". Relational databases do not support nested data in one table.

Comment: I believe what I need is to replace address field with HouseNo, Street, City, Country. So the complete table will look like Id, Name, Salary, HouseNo, Street, City, Country,

Comment: You can use the string functions CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING to parse the value of Address and create the "nested" columns in your SQL table.

Answer (score 1):

Nested subdocuments are the simplest kind of nesting to handle, because you can always flatten these subdocuments out into the top level document.

In your example, the `Address` subdocument can be flattened out into four top-level fields:

- `Address - House No`
- `Address - Street`
- `Address - City`
- `Address - Country`

You lose some information in this flattening, specifically, the knowledge that all four columns are properties of a single entity. But that's inevitable if your target is a a single CSV file (you can avoid losing this information by creating separate `Address` table, for example, but that will result in multiple CSVs).

The trickier kind of flattening is when you have *arrays* of values inside MongoDB. Those cannot be usefully flattened into a single table. You have to invent potentially many tables to properly represent the information.

In addition, if you are not absolutely sold on SQL Server, I'd suggest looking at [MoSQL](http://github.com/stripe/mosql), another open source project that can replicate data from MongoDB into Postgres (it does not support arrays).

In this day and age, you shouldn't have to write code to do this translation.

Comment: I dont think the collection has arrays because I used the simba odbc driver trial version to export the collection to tableau. It created two tables like you said and joined them by id to get the complete data. I am looking into Slamdata now. I am sold out to sql server because I want to generate reports using ssrs. I think for mongodb there is no descent reporting tool